# Doing double - int in java

Tags: java, primitive

For example if I do this:

```
double decPart = 5.57 - 5;
System.out.println(decPart);
```

it returns 0.5700000000000003, instead of just 0.57. I can print it out properly using System.out.printf("%.2f", decPart), but that doesn't solve the problem (Note: the decimal part is not necessarily 2 decimal places). So for example if I try to do this:

```
System.out.println(1.0 - decPart);
```

it would return 0.4299999999999997

Can somebody please explain this behavior and how to fix it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: You are running into issues with *precision*.

Comment: @Reimeus perhaps there is a simpler solution that doesn't require reading a 100 page document.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to [floating point imprecision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems). Floating-point numbers (`float`, `double` in Java) cannot represent some numbers exactly. If you're looking for absolute precision, look into [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

Comment: Thanks, that helps to clear up. I am currently changing the double to String and getting the decimal value this way: `double decPart = Double.parseDouble(n.substring(n.indexOf(‘.’), n.length()));` [Taken from cracking the coding interview]. Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: That still doesn't guarantee you that decimal part can be represented by a double.